# Simplify $\dfrac{\sqrt{m+x}+\sqrt{m-x}}{\sqrt{m+x}-\sqrt{m-x}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify $$\dfrac{\sqrt{m+x}+\sqrt{m-x}}{\sqrt{m+x}-\sqrt{m-x}}$$ if $x=\dfrac{2mn}{n^2+1}$ and $m>0,n>1$.

The solution of the authors starts as follows:
$$\dfrac{\left(\sqrt{m+x}+\sqrt{m-x}\right)^2}{(\sqrt{m+x})^2-(\sqrt{m-x})^2}=\dfrac{m+x+2\sqrt{m^2-x^2}+m-x}{m+x-m+x}=\dfrac{m+\sqrt{m^2-x^2}}{x}=...$$
I don't get the idea behind this. What exactly have they done with the given expression? Thank you!

Comment: Can you understand this: $\frac{a + b}{a - b} = \frac{(a + b)^2}{a^2 - b^2}$. It's called "multiply both denominator and numerator by $a + b$".

Comment: This is a very standard step: to get rid of radicals ("surds") in the denominator $\frac{\text{something}}{\sqrt{A}-\sqrt{B}}$, you multiply both numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{A}+\sqrt{B}$ to obtain $\frac{\text{something}\times(\sqrt{A}+\sqrt{B})}{A-B}$.

Comment: @WhatsUp, yes, I can. $\dfrac{(a+b)^2}{a^2-b^2}=\dfrac{(a+b)^2}{(a-b)(a+b)}=\dfrac{a+b}{a-b}$ if $a\ne -b.$

Comment: Try multiplying by $\frac{\sqrt{m+x}+\sqrt{m-x}}{\sqrt{m+x}+\sqrt{m-x}}$ and simplifying.

Comment: @StinkingBishop, so they have just rationalized the  given expression?

Comment: Then you just set $a = \sqrt{m + x}$ and $b = \sqrt{m - x}$.

Comment: @koki They have, haven't they?

Comment: @koki Is the final answer equal to $\dfrac{n}{2}$?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\bigg(\dfrac{\sqrt{m+x}+\sqrt{m-x}}{\sqrt{m+x}-\sqrt{m-x}}\bigg)
\bigg(\dfrac{\sqrt{m+x}+\sqrt{m-x}}{\sqrt{m+x}+\sqrt{m-x}}\bigg)
\\
\\
=\dfrac{\big(\sqrt{m+x}+\sqrt{m-x}\big)^2}
{(m+x)-(m-x)}\\
\\
=\dfrac{2 \sqrt{m - x} \sqrt{m + x} + 2 m}
{2x}\\
\\
=\dfrac{\sqrt{m^2 - x^2} + m}
{x}
,\space  x=\dfrac{2mn}{n^2+1},\space m>0,\space n>1
\end{align*}

Comment: @YNK   Thanks, I got it